# How to name the rows and columns in dataframe before exporting to excel?

Tags: python, excel, numpy, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(Numpy_Array2)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Results.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array1')
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'Array2')
writer.save()
```

I am trying to export numpy arrays to excel first converting it to dataframes. Each array has 10 rows and 35 columns, what is the best possible way to name each columns and rows ?

Answer (score 1):

To name columns in dataframe you can use

```
df.columns = ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: how do I name the rows ?

Comment: @Tudee92 you need a column of names and then you just set the index of your DataFrame to this column...